# How to get welcome messages in AWS Lex (lambda in Python)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am using Aws Lex for constructing chatbots. I had a scenario where I need to have welcome message initially without user input so that I can give a direction to the user in my chatbot.

Answer (score 7):

You need to work that scenario using API call to start a context with your user.

**You can follow these steps:**

- You need to create an Intent called `AutoWelcomeMessage`.
- Create a `Slot type` with only one value i.e: `HelloMe`.
- Create an Utterances `HelloMessage`.
- Create a `Slot` as follow: Required, name: `answer`, Slot Type: `HelloMe`, Prompt: 'AutoWelcomePrompt'.
- Pick Amazon Lambda for your `Fulfillment` that will send a response to your user. I.e:

*Hello user, may I help?* **(Here the user will enter another `Intent` and your Bot will respond)**.

Now, start a conversation with your User, just call via API your Lex Bot and send an intention with Intent `AutoWelcomeMessage`, that call starts a context with your Lex Bot and the `fulfillment` will execute your Lambda.

Comment: i am confused with 5th point do i need to make  my own lambda or i need to select prebuilt one ?

Comment: @RonakShethia you can pick a prebuilt or your own lambda function.  I recommend creating an own lambda function to customize your welcome message.

Comment: Hello, Ele, how can i write my lambda function? On dispatch we compare the intent "if (intentName === 'AutoWelcomeMessage')'". It means, we need to get IntentName before showing it as initial message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your own website or an app for integrating the chatbot, then you can send some unique welcome text from that website/app when it loads for the first time i.e `on load method` to the amazon lex. And in amazon lex you can create a welcome intent and put exact same text as utterance.

This way, when the website/app loads, it will send text to amazon lex and lex can fire the welcome intent and reply to it.