# Can bot start/initiate the conversation?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wanted to know that if in any case it is possible for the aws lex bot to initiate the conversation with the user?
i wanted to deploy the chatbot on website and as soon as any user clicks on the bot it should send the first greeting message.
If it is possible than how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get welcome messages in AWS Lex (lambda in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476742/how-to-get-welcome-messages-in-aws-lex-lambda-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES. It is possible for the bot to initiate the conversation. However, this can be done using simple Javascript implementation and is nothing to do with Lex. Subsequent conversations can be routed via Lex. This is a common practice in chatbots. Let me know if you need a code sample which shows this kind of implementation.

Comment: Hi..! Thank you for the answer. It will be a great help if you can share the JScript code for the same @JayaPrakashKommu

Comment: Please go through the below git link. Note: Modify the value of the variables in line no: 205, 206, 207 as per your lex project https://github.com/jpsmartbots/chatbots/blob/master/firstBot/index.html